# What does this command actually do in django?

Tags: python, django

What does this actually do, & what is the default superuser account that is created ?

```
./manage.py  runscript -v 2 create_superuser
```

Comment: Isn't that [django-command-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/#Current_Command_Extensions) command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have run `syncdb`, and `django.contrib.auth` is among your apps, this will create a user that has the 'superuser' bit set.  Such a user implicitly has all permissions, and most usefully, can always log into the `admin` interface for your project.  You might want to do this if you enable `auth` sometime later than when you first started your django project (because it turned out you needed auth after all).

Comment: Or if you have ran `syncdb` with `--noinput` switch.